# How to setup react routing for detail and create page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently dealing with routing issues in my reactjs app.

I need to have an URL for the following pages:

/employees 
/employees/5 
/employees/create

But when clicking on the /employees page, I'll get redirected to /employees/create.

Anybody know what I'm missing here?

```
<Router>
    <NavBar />
    <Container maxWidth="lg" className="container-padding">
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/employees" component={EmployeeOverview} />
            <Route exact path='/employees/create' component={EmployeeDetail} />
            <Route path='/employees/:employeeId' component={EmployeeDetail} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </Container>
</Router>
```

NavBar component:

```
<List>
    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/">
        <ListItemIcon>
            <Icons.Home />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Home" />
    </ListItem>
    <Divider />
    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/employees">
        <ListItemIcon>
            <Icons.Group />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Werknemers" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/employees/5">
        <ListItemIcon>
            <Icons.Group />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Werknemer details" />
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

EmployeeOverview component

```
export default class EmployeeOverview extends Component<any, any> {

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Box mt={2}>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.props.history.push('/employees/create')}>
                        Werknemer toevoegen
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the component also ?

Comment: you can use history.push() property of react-router

Comment: @SangramBadi added navbar component.

Comment: @RonakKhangaonkar I'm afraid that wouldn't work in my context. Atleast not if I want to keep it clean

Comment: Please add your `EmployeeOverview` component, you should have a redirection in this component that is trigger on mount.

Comment: @Darkilen you're right! There is a history.push in that component. When removed, it seems to be working. But it should only happen `onClick` instead of when it loads the page.

Comment: I've fixed it by changing the onclick like this: `onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('/employees/create')}}`

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was not that the routing was incorrect. The routing was working as it should work.

The issue lies in the `EmployeeOverview` page. 
there was an `onClick` event on a button that would redirect me to the `employees/create` page when I clicked on it. But it was written to self-execute onload.

So instead of this

```
<Button onClick={this.props.history.push('/employees/create')}>
    Werknemer toevoegen
</Button>
```

I wrote this and solved it

```
<Button onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('/employees/create')}}>
    Werknemer toevoegen
</Button>
```

Credits to [Darkilen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9150452/darkilen) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavLink in your List to achieve this.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

After Import wrap your each `<ListItem>` in `<NavLink>` like this.

```
<NavLink
    to='/employees/5'>
  <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>
            <Icons.Group />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Werknemer details" />
    </ListItem>
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to comment out the following line and keep rest of the code as before

```
<Route exact path='/employees/create' component={EmployeeDetail} />
```

Hope it will work